# Python implementation of set relations

Tags: python

How would I implement the following using python? I've tried using lambda expressions and a few other methods, but I'm not getting the desired results. Basically, I should receive a set of relations that satisfy the check. I.E they have to be divisible by each other, so `{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3),...(6,6)}.`

Here's the actual question:

In Python, set a variable say `S = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`; then do as follows: "List all the ordered pairs in the relation `R = {(a,b) : a divides b}` on the set `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`."

Comment: Please show us the code that you've tried.

Comment: divisible by each other is different from a divides b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by list comprehension -

```
S = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
result = [ (x,y) for x in S for y in S if y%x==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` within a list comprehension,and as you want they be divisible by each other you can use the condition `i%j==0 or j%i==0` :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [(i,j) for i,j in product(S,repeat=2) if i%j==0 or j%i==0]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 5), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: nice use of itertools,, i guess it is same as zip(S,S).. isn't it?

Comment: @jazzz Not at all! that `zip` will give the pairs with same value!

Answer (score 0):

[{(a,b) : a/b} for a in S for b in S]